# Pro/Cons of exceptions over the errorString() method

Tags: java, c++, qt, exception, error-handling

I normally code in C++ using Qt framework. And for error handling I use the standard that Qt uses, which is calling a function like `errorString()` when a function behaves unexpectedly. For the current project I'm working on, I need to write my code in Java, and it is common to use Exceptions with **try-catch-finally** mechanism in Java.

My question is, will it be a big mistake to use `errorString()` like approach for error handling in Java. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using exceptions other than `errorString()`.

Thank you.

Comment: One advantage is, that you don't have to implement your errorString logic by yourself. Common Java exception handling is a build-in feature! Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html

Comment: " will it be a big mistake to use errorString() like approach for error handling in Java" Yes. It's a mistake is QT too, but there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Note that using exceptions right in Java is hard, it's easy to create a messy spaghetti unless you are careful. So find and read some guides, let IDE help you as much as it can, and keep an open mind to notice when you start doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The advantages are (according to Oracle's [Advantages of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html) article):

- Separating error-handling code from "regular" code
- Propagating errors up the call stack
- Grouping and differentiating error types

It is generally a good idea to write idiomatic code, sticking to the conventions and practices of the language you develop in. As I see it, that's an advantage in itself.

As far as cons go, at the top of my head:

- It's really annoying to lazy programmers because you have to surround your code in try/catch, this may make it slightly more difficult to ignore the exceptions (I see this as an advantage).
- It's easily misused by programmers who are new to the concept, and in turn you get severely uglified codebase on top of an arcane home-brewed error reporting system.

As far as whether or not it will be a mistake goes, well, as long as the entire team are Qt masterminds and have to write something in Java on an accidental basis and this code will *never* have to be managed by anyone who is supposed to be a Java expert, then sure - make a familiar environment for yourself and your team. But in any other circumstance, I highly recommend that you use exceptions instead.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is solely dependent on your implementation... See, for instance, you can catch a particular exception, wrap it and throw its parent exception ( a mechanism which is very widely used..). This way you can have a hierarchy of exceptions and you handle all exceptions in a general way... Suppose you have a DB and assume for some reason you get a connection exception... Now, you dont have to worry about handling that exception there and then.. you say that your method "throws" this exception and let the caller worry about it..the caller might wait for some time and then try to connect to DB again,,, Furthermore you can use finally to release resources/clean up... You are doing much more than errorString() (printing an error message..) . You can also include logging in here if you want to..